# What does "snap to same target" in "face nearest" do?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I tried that setting but I don't see any difference, so when will i actually use that setting and what it does? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you actually read right through the Blender docs that you were pointed to in your previous question? It's under the "Target Selection" section here: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/controls/snapping.html#target-selection

Comment: I did , what it does for me in blender is completely different from it said in the docs, it said it will "snap only to target that source was initially near". but in face it does nothing for me

Comment: I have to admit that the manual isn't very clear. I've never used that setting so can't really help.